# Store clusters terms in variables created using a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, variables

I have a python script where I have gone through a list of samples and extracted the features and clustered the document features. I want to save each cluster to a variable created within the loop itself.

In order to do that, I have declared a dictionary and created a set of variables that will be named `cluster0`, `cluster1`, `cluster2` and so on and stored the list of words in each cluster to the newly created variables using the following method.

```
    d = {}
    feature_set =[]

    if(len(filtered_terms)!=0):
        for m in filtered_terms:
            print(' %s' % m, end='')
            feature_set.append(m)
        for w in cluster_terms:
            for b in filtered_terms:
                if (w != b):
                    print(' %s' % w, end='')
                    feature_set.append(w)
    else:
        for h in cluster_terms:
            print(' %s' % h, end='')
            feature_set.append(h)

    for f in range(0, i+1):
        #globals()['string%s' % f] = feature_set
        d["cluster{0}".format(f)] = feature_set

    print()
print("Clusters stored in a dictionary of Variables")

print ()
for k in d:
    print (k)
    print (d[k])
```

The original cluster data is shown as follows.

```
Top terms per cluster:
Cluster 0: wilson adam presid cleveland roosevelt lincoln grant monro fillmor parti
Cluster 1: instrument flute drum drum flute instrument bar bar sound sound instrument trumpet trumpet music music concert concert flute
Cluster 2: string cello violin instrument violin violin violin cello cello cello string string string string string string bow bow bow bow instrument instrument instrument cello cello cello violin violin violin music music music music instrument instrument instrument
Cluster 3: languag chines german italian arab spanish spoken swahili ghana vietnames
Cluster 4: newton string kangaroo guitar ford singapor penguin uruguay romania piano
Cluster 5: eleph beetl polar leopard speci wolv bear wolf fur
```

*Ignoring the repetition of words in cluster 2*, I tried to print the word list stored in the variables created using the dictionary `d` using the following method which is shown above as well.

```
for k in d:
    print (k)
    print (d[k])
```

But I get the following output where the variable names are properly created as `cluster0`, `cluster1`, `cluster2`, etc. but only the content of cluster 5 (the last cluster in the original cluster) is being stored repetitively to all the variables.

**Output**

```
cluster2
[u'eleph', u'beetl', u'polar', u'leopard', u'speci', u'wolv', u'bear', u'wolf', u'fur']
cluster3
[u'eleph', u'beetl', u'polar', u'leopard', u'speci', u'wolv', u'bear', u'wolf', u'fur']
cluster0
[u'eleph', u'beetl', u'polar', u'leopard', u'speci', u'wolv', u'bear', u'wolf', u'fur']
cluster1
[u'eleph', u'beetl', u'polar', u'leopard', u'speci', u'wolv', u'bear', u'wolf', u'fur']
cluster4
[u'eleph', u'beetl', u'polar', u'leopard', u'speci', u'wolv', u'bear', u'wolf', u'fur']
cluster5
[u'eleph', u'beetl', u'polar', u'leopard', u'speci', u'wolv', u'bear', u'wolf', u'fur']
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution. It was a mere matter of changing the location of where I created the dictionary. Since the dictionary was created within the top most loop where I was iterating through `i` already, the following `for` loop continued to go through the parent loop and ended by initializing the variables with the `feature_set` recorded during the last `i` loop.

Hence, I modified the dictionary initialization over `i`'s loop as follows and it words now.

```
d = {}
for i in range(true_k):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i, end='')
    cluster_terms = []
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
       ...

    feature_set =[]

    if(len(filtered_terms)!=0):
        for m in filtered_terms:
            print(' %s' % m, end='')
            feature_set.append(m)
        for w in cluster_terms:
            for b in filtered_terms:
                if (w != b):
                    print(' %s' % w, end='')
                    feature_set.append(w)
        d["cluster{0}".format(i)] = feature_set
    else:
        for h in cluster_terms:
            print(' %s' % h, end='')
            feature_set.append(h)
        d["cluster{0}".format(i)] = feature_set

        #globals()['string%s' % f] = feature_set
    #d["cluster{0}".format(i)] = feature_set

    print()
print("Clusters stored in a dictionary of Variables")

print ()
for k in d:
    print (k)
    print (d[k])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `feature_set` is a flat list, like you have printed out.

This code:

```
for f in range(0, i+1):
    d["cluster{0}".format(f)] = feature_set
```

simply assigns this list to every cluster, so the end result is very much expected. For your piece of code to work, one idea would be to have your `feature_set` as 2-dimensional list like this:

`feature_set = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10], [11,12]]`

```
for f in range(0, i+1):
    d["cluster{0}".format(f)] = feature_set[f]
```

`feature_set[f]` is then content of your cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Though I did actually get what I required, I guess having it in a 2D list might be a viable way when it comes to accessing the content later.